# How to check if 'Box<Any>' contains 'Unit' in a short expression?

Tags: casting, rust, box, any

What is a convenient way to check a `Box<Any>` is `()` (created by `Box::new(())`).

Currently I have this, but I suspect there might be a more compact way to express this since the assignment seems redundant.

```
pub fn some_function(value: Box<Any>) {
    if let Some(&()) = value.downcast_ref() {
        // pass
    } else {
        panic!();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using [`Any::is`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html#method.is) method, eg:

```
assert!(value.is::<()>());
```